# Active menu trail with 2 menu items linking to same content

Tags: 6, theming, routes

On a D6 site, I have a content accessible by 2 ways in my primary links:

- Section A :

  - "my content"
- Section B:

  - "my content"

My problem is that the active trail is set on Section A, but I would like to highlight section B instead.

My breadcrumb (with [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) set to "use the menu structure to set the breadcrumb trail") also displays path to Section A instead of Section B.

With [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) module (reactions => menu), I've set the active menu to Section B. This changed my breadcrumb which now displays the good section (B).
But unfortunately my primary links remains highlighted on A.

If I switch to Garland, section B is highlighted in my primary links, so obviously it is a custom theme issue, but I can't find where exactly. `theme_menu_item()` is not overriden... All I'm able to grab in my preprocess functions is a menu with the active_trail already set.

I've also tried [Menu Position](http://drupal.org/project/menu_position) module, without success...

Any hints are greatly appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: can you post your template.php code here http://codepad.org

Comment: here is a cleaned version: http://codepad.org/QRkIHK3n